# REGEX not functioning properly, preg_match

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

This REGEX is not working as I would like it to...

```
/<ol class=\"references\">\/(.*?)<\/ol>/s
```

I'm using it in conjunction with `preg_match` in PHP.

```
preg_match_all("/<ol class=\"references\">\/(.*?)<\/ol>/s", $file, $mats);
```

When I put it in http://regex101.com/, it seems like the issue is that it wants the string desired to match/parse to be `<ol class="references">/text here</ol>`?

It states: `\/ matches the character / literally`

However, I want the snippet of REGEX and PHP to parse `<ol class="references">text here</ol>`

Comment: This is why you [shouldn't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: For particular reasons of my own I am using regex.

Comment: I am aware of DOM parsers. :) Thank you.

Comment: @JohnConde This is why it is ok to parse HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/764357

Comment: Thanks @LegoStormtroopr. I am looking for something lightweight, I am parsing lightweight text, which regex suits well. I had posted by question as to receive answers complying with my specification. Furthermore, I could be doing an assignment? I've heard this mantra about regex and HTML many times.

Comment: If you are aware why you are using your regex? You are just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Whether or not regex suits my needs is not my question, though thank you for the advice. Regex is efficient and pithy to code, and it works, especially for my situation. I find immediately posting "oh regex is awful for parsing html" unnecessary, its a mantra I've heard many times, and it doesn't take into account the actual implementation the OP is using. I'm interested in why the problem in the question I mentioned is happening, not whether or not regex suits my situation. I could be studying CS theory for all you know.

Comment: @lmat there are legitimate reasons to use Regex to search through HTML. If the OP needs just the text in the `ol.class` tag, and knows there won't be other class values, then regex is suitable without the expense of parsing the whole DOM. The OP has a reason, and this isn't an unreasonable task for regex.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you, I don't need to import a whole DOM parsing library and having to parse the whole DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct `\/` matches a literal slash, so your pattern can't match on:

```
<ol class="references">text here</ol>
```

As the expression *requires* a literal `/` after the first `>`. Just remove that and it should work as required:

```
<ol class=\"references\">(.*?)<\/ol>
```

If there are occasionally slashes (`/`) in the inner text of the element, that you don't want to capture, you can do a quantified match - `?` - like so:

```
<ol class=\"references\">\/?(.*?)<\/ol>
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '(' in /home/content/76/10008776/html/stuck.php on line 10

Comment: Or Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 28 in /home/content/76/10008776/html/stuck.php on line 10

Comment: Actually, no thery're the right way around. And the regex is valid according to regex101. Was it copied correctly?

Comment: ya, i did copy it correctly. it did say valid, however in php I get warnings